# VS2015 update 2: "Initialize Interactive with Project" option missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, c#-interactive

According to the Visual Studio 2015 update 2 [release notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx#CsharpAndVB), it is now possible to initialize the C# interactive environment with the context of a selected project. This feature is further described in these [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/04/02/whats-new-for-c-and-vb-in-visual-studio/) [posts](https://johnkoerner.com/csharp/sending-a-project-to-the-c-interactive-window-in-vs-2015-update-2/). However, the "Initialize interactive with project" menu option they talk about and show in screenshots simply isn't present for me (though I *do* see the related new "Execute in interactive" option when I select code in the editor).

I'm using:

[image]

Any clue what might be wrong? Does anyone else see this feature?

Update: Just to prove it's really not there:

[image]

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this?

Comment: @Vaindil I noticed recently that the option is in the list now, but I have no idea what changed to put it there; certainly nothing I did on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project and you'll see the option in the context menu.

Comment: No, it isn't there. I've quadruple-checked. But it is for you?

Comment: Yes, it is. I didn't do anything special other than installing Update 2.  I'm working in a web application, while you're in a console app. Can you try another project type?

Comment: Same thing with a web app. Anyway, the screenshot in the second blog post is from a console app, so it seems like it should work...

Answer (score 0):

Within the code window Right-Click you will see it there. Perform the right click as if you are trying to right click on a function. You can execute an entire function.

You can actually right click anywhere in the code window.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 2, and I can see the expected menu option by right-clicking a console project, so it should be available for you too.

I just wonder if you can see and use **View > Other Windows > C# Interactive**

Maybe if you double check the installed components through the Visual Studio setup and/or do a Repair by Visual Studio setup can bring it back for you.

Comment: Yes, that option is there and it brings up the window correctly; it's just specifically the "Initialize Interactive With Project" menu option that's missing. I will probably try a repair install at some point if all else fails.